# foreach assign wrong id to wire model after calling search function again

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a weird problem with Livewire, I am unable to identify why this is happening.

The Problem is: I have a list populated from foreach loop, and the data in foreach loop comes from the search function. For example, I have two list items on the list, and I update some data on them using the dropdown available, if i update the first item and recall the search function the data is updated and now only one item left in the list but now it is with wrong wire model id, but the data come from search function is correct but livewire assign the wrong id to it.

To understand the issue properly, please watch this short [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BauJvFRq4CbAZNBoLhSxvLbcPtDcF6k-/view?usp=sharing).

**Relevant Codes:**

**Blade**

```
<div>
    @foreach ($this->result as $data)
    <div>
        <span class="has-float-label" style="width: 190px;">
            <select wire:model="list_session_picker.id.{{ $data->id }}" wire:key="sessionList-{{ $data->id }}" required class="form-control">                                                            
            @foreach ($sessionData as $session)
            {{ $this->isDetailsExist ? ($this->list_session_picker['id'][$data->id] = "$data->student_session_id") : null }} {{-- This line of code selects the default value of the item in the database, so t will be sow as selected --}}
                <option value="{{ $session->id }}">{{ $session->session }}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>            
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-light" wire:click.prevent="promote">
         Promote all
    </button>
</div>
```

**Componenet**

```
public $result = [], $list_session_picker = [], $selectedItems = [];
public $isDetailsExist = true;

public function search()
{        
    $search = SchoolStudent::query();        

    if (!empty($this->search_session_picker && $this->search_class_picker && $this->search_medium_picker)) {
        $search->where('student_session_id', $this->search_session_picker);
        $search->where('student_class_id', $this->search_class_picker);
        $search->where('student_medium', $this->search_medium_picker);

        $this->result = $search
                ->whereNull('date_of_graduate')
                ->with(['session:id,session', 'class:id,name'])
                ->get();
    }
}

public function resetFields()
{        
    $this->selectedItems = [];
    $this->list_session_picker = [];
    $this->result = [];
    $this->isDetailsExist = true;
}

public function promote()
{
    if (count($this->selectedItems) > 0) {
        foreach ($this->selectedItems as $ikey => $sitems) {
            if (isset($this->selectedItems[$ikey]) &&  $this->selectedItems[$ikey] !== false) {
                foreach ($this->list_session_picker as $lskey => $session) {
                    $selectedStudent = SchoolStudent::findOrFail($sitems);
                    $selectedStudent->student_session_id = $this->list_session_picker[$lskey][$selectedStudent->id];
                    $selectedStudent->update();
                }
                unset($session);
            }
        }
        unset($sitems);   
        $this->resetFields();         
        $this->search();
    }
}
```

To refresh the list I am calling the search method again with already selected values, but is there any other way please suggest, because if I am not doing the search again, dom is all correct but the updated item has not been removed from the list, but I prefer to call the search function again

Comment: If I look at your  video, it seems your dropdown is wrapped in a `wire:ignore` and thus won't get updated

Comment: @Yinci oh !! Thank you again, for pointing it, problem solved

Comment: @Yinci, good spot! If that was the problem, you should put in an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment seems to have solved the issue, I'll leave it as answer so it can be accepted.

Within the video, the dropdown is wrapped in a `wire:ignore`. This prevents the dropdown from ever getting updated.

Read more about it in the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#ignoring-dom-changes).